# Add sequence column to a dataframe depending on sequential counts of unique variables in another column

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a random list of id variables that may or may not be repeated. The order is important. I need to create another column which would be a continuing sequence depending on the addition of non-repeated unique variables for each row. For example:

```
   id seq
1 163   1
2   2   2
3   4   3
4 163   3
5 176   4
6 163   4
7   2   4
8   3   5
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with duplicated i..e `with(df1, cumsum(!duplicated(id)))`

Comment: Thanks - works perfect!